# flask --help displays Error: Could not import 'server'

Tags: python, macos, flask, iterm2

I cloned project https://github.com/sayler8182/MockServer, go to project directory and run ./scripts/init.sh

Init.sh code:

```py
pip3 install virtualenv
python3 -m venv venv

. venv/bin/activate

pip3 install -r requirements.txt
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```

The output from this script:

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyrsistent!=0.17.0,!=0.17.1,!=0.17.2,>=0.14.0 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from jsonschema>=3.0.1->flasgger->-r requirements.txt (line 2)) (0.19.3)
Requirement already satisfied: greenlet!=0.4.17 in ./venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from SQLAlchemy>=1.4.18->Flask-SQLAlchemy->-r requirements.txt (line 7)) (2.0.1)
Error: Could not import 'server'.

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'db'.
Error: Could not import 'server'.

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.

Error: No such command 'db'.
Error: Could not import 'server'.

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
Try 'flask --help' for help.
```

When I print env variables:

```
FLASK_APP=server.py
VIRTUAL_ENV=/Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv
PS1=(venv) %{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)
VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT=(venv)
rvm_hook=
_=/usr/bin/env
```

I can see FLASK_APP and VIRTUAL_ENV.
When I run:

```
flask --help
```

I see in the output:

```
Error: Could not import 'server'.

Usage: flask [OPTIONS] COMMAND [ARGS]...
```

I tried few times reinstall flask in the project folder:

```
pip3 uninstall flask
pip3 install Flask
```

with success:

```
Collecting Flask
  Using cached Flask-2.2.2-py3-none-any.whl (101 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=2.2.2 in /Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask) (2.2.2)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=2.0 in /Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask) (2.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=8.0 in /Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask) (8.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: importlib-metadata>=3.6.0 in /Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask) (5.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=3.0 in /Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask) (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: zipp>=0.5 in /Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from importlib-metadata>=3.6.0->Flask) (3.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=2.0 in /Users/user1/Project/MockServer/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2>=3.0->Flask) (2.1.1)
Installing collected packages: Flask
Successfully installed Flask-2.2.2
```

with success. But error with `flask --help` still exists.

Pip, Python details:

```
pip3 -V
pip 22.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip (python 3.10)

python3 -V
Python 3.10.7
```

I will be very grateful for any advice on how to fix this error

```
Error: Could not import 'server'.
```

Update:

- I can run this project on Apple Terminal, but not in iTerm2 :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems FLASK_APP is getting exported to server.py automatically. It doesn't need to be set.
So by unsetting it before running flask commands should resolve the issue.

`unset FLASK_APP`

Then you can proceed with the commands,

```
flask db init
flask db migrate
flask db upgrade
```